# Sigma.js v2 Label Size proportional like v1

Tags: javascript, typescript, sigma.js

is there a possibility in Sigma.js v2 to make the labels size proportional, like the first Sigma version ?
Has anyone an idea ?

I have already looked in the documentation and code and can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Add custom label Renderer.

> you can do it by defining a custom label renderer for instance. Here is how ipysigma does it for instance: https://github.com/medialab/ipysigma/blob/master/src/custom-label.ts *by Yomguithereal*

https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/issues/1334